# Cycle through array recursively PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a function to cycle through simple array recursively

```
$values = [
    'sizes' => ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
    'colors' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    'types' => ['Short', 'Long'],
];
```

To get this result:

```
foreach($sizes as $size){
    foreach($colors as $color){
        foreach($types as $type){
            $str = "$size $color $type";
            // S Red Short
            // S Red Long
            // S Blue Short
            // ...
            // M Red Long
            // M Blue Short
            // M Blue Long
            // ...
            // XL Blue Long
            // XL Green Short
            // XL Green Long
        }
    }
}
```

My array is completely variable, I can have:

```
$values = [
    'sizes' => ['S', 'M'],
    'colors' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'White', 'Black'],
];
```

Or

```
$values = [
    'sizes' => ['S', 'M', 'L'],
    'colors' => ['Red', 'Blue'],
    'type' => ['short']
];
```

Does anyone have a suggestion or an answer?
Thank in advance

Comment: Looks to me like you already wrote the perfect solution. How about telling us about edge cases? Is it always 3 sub arrays owned by a single array? what other situations could happen

Comment: @RiggsFolly The current solution is not recursive. The question then becomes, of course, why does Alex197 need a recursive solution? And: Does Alex197 know what recursively means?

Comment: I want to specify thant the array $values is variables and all its content too. I can have 2 arrays like 5

Comment: How it will behave when one of the sub-array has no elements remain and others still have elements to traverse?

Comment: I put my expected outcome in comments in the foreach. It's not enough because I don't have a definite amount of foreach, I can have 1 foreach or 5.

Comment: @Alex197 consider 3rd one `type` is having one element, `colors` having 2 and `sizes` having 3, so in this case for 2nd and 3rd concatenation how the output will look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this recursively is:

```
<?php

$properties = [
    'sizes'  => ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
    'colors' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    'types'  => ['Short', 'Long'],
];


function recurseProperties($properties, $output = '')
{
    // are there still values left in the properties array?
    if (count($properties) > 0) {
        // pick off first array from the properties
        $values = array_shift($properties);
        // do all values recursively
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            recurseProperties($properties, "$output $value");
        }
    } else {
        // output what we have so far
        echo trim($output) . PHP_EOL;
    }      
}

recurseProperties($properties);
```

The code is reasonably self-explanatory. I added some comments in the code. The output is:

```
 S Red Short
 S Red Long
 S Blue Short
 S Blue Long
 S Green Short
 S Green Long
 M Red Short
 M Red Long
 M Blue Short
 M Blue Long
 M Green Short
 M Green Long
 L Red Short
 L Red Long
 L Blue Short
 L Blue Long
 L Green Short
 L Green Long
 XL Red Short
 XL Red Long
 XL Blue Short
 XL Blue Long
 XL Green Short
 XL Green Long
```

Here is a [PHP fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b4e9d1d5742e2d5d32d59ac0379e0ae39613653).

Comment: This is the result I expected, I'll try to apply it to my code which is more complex than this example. Thank you !

Comment: @Alex197 Well, I cheated a bit. I echo the output inside the recursive function. This means I don't have to return it from the function. Normally you would return the result, which means you need to carry forward what you already have, just like I do already, but you also have to carry backward the results you have. That makes the algorithm slightly more complex. You could cheat there as well and use a `global` variable to get the results.

Comment: I made it work by returning the concatenation as an array containing the 3 values instead of a string, thank you for your help, it unlocked me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CrossJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-crossjoin) from [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

```
    $values = [
    'sizes' => ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
    'colors' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    'types' => ['Short', 'Long'],
];

$valuesCollection = collect($values);

$collection = collect($valuesCollection->first());
$valuesCollection->shift();


$matrix = $collection
  ->crossJoin(...$valuesCollection->values())
  ->map(function($value){
    return implode(' ',array_values($value));
  });

dd($matrix);
```

Live Demo [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/7ad61f97-2caf-4c36-af29-f4ad3aef0dcd)

Comment: Very good answer that also works fine, thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements are same in all array, you can use one for loop and just iterate all like, if number of elements are not same, you can take the largest one from them and assign empty string as default value in case element not present.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($values['sizes']); $i++) {
   $size = $values['sizes'][$i] ?? "";
   $color = $values['colors'][$i] ?? "";
   $type = $values['types'][$i] ?? "";
   $str = $size . $color . $type;
}
```

This one option I can think of. may not work in all scenario, but based on the sample provided by you, I can think of this.I do not think you should use recursive for this. Recursive solution may eat your memory, so try to avoid that.

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef15ad33ced515d068d9b1f825bd4543be01ea33)

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, the arrays have variable sizes

Comment: @Alex197, then you can take the largest subarray and check if no element present, sue a empty string or go with 3 loops.